# $event.stopPropogation() is not allowing to load file in an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, iframe

I have ng-click for both parent div and child div so to trigger the click event of child i am giving $event.stopPropogation()
and that click will load file in an iframe.

but when i pass $event.stopPropogation() to the child div the content is not loading and when i remove it ,its getting loading

I dnt understand where i am doing wrong and there are no errors at all

here is the html

```
<div ng-class="{'col-xs-6': myVar=='something'}">
<div class="panel panel-default panel-height" ng-repeat="candidateInfo in aCandidateDetails track by $index" ng-click="fnInterviewView(candidateInfo.name)">
    <div class="panel-heading header-background">
        <div stop-watch time="xyz" name="candidateInfo.name" time-of-interview="candidateInfo.doi" class="stop-watch"></div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2"><a style="cursor:pointer" class="pull-right">{{candidateInfo.name}}</a></div>
            <div class="col-xs-offset-9"><a style="cursor:pointer" ng-click="fnVar(candidateInfo.name, candidateInfo.filepath,$index);$event.stopPropogation()" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="{{'#'+'collapse'+'_' + name}}">{{candidateInfo.name}} resume</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div></div>
```

here is the controller code below

```
angular.module('hrPortalApp')
.controller('candidateInterviewCtrl', function($scope, $state, $sce, getCandidateInterviewListService) {
    getCandidateInterviewListService.fnGetCandidateDetails("xyz").then(function(response) {
        $scope.aCandidateDetails = response;
        console.log(response);
        $scope.toggle = "accor"
    });
    $scope.file = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('http://localhost:4000/api/uploads/574ed76718153dac202679b9_resume.pdf');

    $scope.fnVar = function(name, filepath, index, event) {
        $scope.file = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('http://localhost:4000/' + filepath);
        $scope.checkVar = !$scope.checkVar;
        if ($scope.checkVar) {
            $scope.myVar = "something";
        } else {
            $scope.myVar = false;
        }
    };
    $scope.fnInterviewView = function(name) {
        $state.go('main.Topics', {
            "candidateDetails": $scope.aCandidateDetails,
            "name": name
        })
    };

});
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Pass the $event to the $scope.fnVar function and do the stop propagation after the work is done like below and not in the html....

```
$scope.fnVar = function(name, filepath, index, event) {
 $scope.file = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('http://localhost:4000/' +    filepath);
 $scope.checkVar = !$scope.checkVar;
 if ($scope.checkVar) {
    $scope.myVar = "something";
 } else {
    $scope.myVar = false;
 }
 event.stopPropagation();
};
```

Comment: yes i did that but still im unable to load the file

Comment: What happens when you remove event.stopPropagation? Does the file load? I know it will trigger the click event on the parent div, but still. Also try adding a timeout for the event.stopPropagation to see if that works. If yes, then you need to stop propagating right after the file has completed loading.

Comment: when I remove stop propagation the file loads but it will trigger parent click event.

Comment: Could you please explain in detail about timeout thing @Srijith

Comment: Just do 
    $timeout(function(){
      event.stopPropagation();
    }, 5000);

Though this is not advised, its just to check if the event.stopPropagation is indeed causing the file loading to stop. Just my quick guess